# how to get other fields from user() function on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to get other fields from user() function on codeigniter.

I tried `print_r(user())` and i get a bunch of columns but not the column I wanted to get the value of.

Usually I use `user('id')` to get the value of the id, but I want to get a specific field, but when I tried `user('newlyAddedColumnName')` it gives me the same result as `print_r(user())`

I think there is a file in which you can set which columns can be access with but I cant find the documentation, its all leading me to session which I do not want.

Thanks, for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the session library, it's easy to use

```
$this->session->userdata();
```

or

```
$this->session->userdata('id')
```

Comment: yeah.. i should, I just thought its a built in function its accessing directly from database, but i was wrong. it was just an improvised session functionality. Thanks for the help though! problem with tracing somebody's code ..